# Is there a way to disclose if the Mac OS Menu Bar text colour is black or white?

Tags: macos

I'm using Swiftbar to display a menu. My menu has an SF image as the clickable item, which I've rendered using palette format, as opposed to letting Swiftbar text pick up whatever the menubar text colour is.

So, if the wallpaper image changes to a darker image, the menu bar text changes to be white; if lighter, the menu bar text changes to be white. But, because my SF image is coded to be black, it means that it doesn't work so well when the wallpaper changes.

What I'd like to do is check what colour the menu bar text is after every wallpaper change, and use that colour when coding the palette colour for the SF image. Is there a way to discover this via command line?

(am yet to find any code that can do this, so nothing to add to this section)

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to detect the menu bar text color.

If you provide a custom image, you can detect the menu appearance at the time the image is rendered:

```
let image = NSImage(size: imageSize, flipped: false) { rect in
    if NSAppearance.current?.bestMatch(from: [.aqua, .darkAqua]) == .darkAqua {
        NSLog("Menu bar is dark")
    } else {
        NSLog("Menu bar is light")
    }

    // Draw image...    
}
```

In your case, you can define your symbol palette using dynamic colors with dark and light variants, and the system will choose the correct color automatically.

You can use Xcode's asset catalog to define your dynamic colors.  You can also define your colors in code:

```
let color = NSColor(name: nil) { (appearance: NSAppearance) in
    if appearance.bestMatch(from: [.aqua, .darkAqua]) == .darkAqua {
        return NSColor.systemRed
    } else {
        return NSColor.systemBlue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Darren - I think I managed to solve it with a speedy enough solution to take a 1*1 pixel screen shot of the Apple Icon in the screen top left, and then assess the rgba color for that image using ImagMagick:

```
/usr/sbin/screencapture -R25,25,1,1 -t png /tmp/x.png;/opt/homebrew/bin/convert /tmp/x.png sparse-color:
```

Comment: Would you explain your solution a bit more please? I run this command in terminal and get "zsh: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/convert" so perhaps I'm missing some library/utility I need to install via homebrew? EDIT: I install ImageMagick now this command returns "0,0,srgba(84,94,144,1) 1,0,srgba(60,72,129,1) 0,1,srgba(60,72,128,1) 1,1,srgba(59,73,129,1) % " but I'm not really sure what it's saying :-)

Comment: ChatGPT figured out the results are for a 2x2 set of pixels even though the screencapture is only 1x1 pixels, however, it's not capturing the Apple Icon. I did a screenshot and analyzed it in a picture editor--the Apple icon is 55 pixels in from the left edge and 40 pixels down. So I issued the command `/usr/sbin/screencapture -R 55,40,1,1 -t png /tmp/x.png;/opt/homebrew/bin/convert /tmp/x.png sparse-color:` and get result `0,0,srgba(73,70,162,1) 1,0,srgba(73,71,162,1) 0,1,srgba(73,71,161,1) 1,1,srgba(73,70,161,1) %` which is still the blueish part of screen, not the 255,255,255 I'm expecting.

Comment: Accounting for Retina Display using 'double pixels', what is working for me is `/usr/sbin/screencapture -R 25,20,1,1 -t png /tmp/x.png;/opt/homebrew/bin/convert /tmp/x.png sparse-color:;rm /tmp/x.png` yielding results `0,0,srgba(255,255,255,1) 1,0,srgba(255,255,255,1) 0,1,srgba(255,255,255,1) 1,1,srgba(255,255,255,1) %` (and deleting the tmp capture file)